# What do you call a sick person who is lying in bed?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

Some conditions require that a person lie in bed all the time until recovered. Is there a name for such conditions or people experiencing them at the moment?

For example,

> I am currently `<bed sick>` and can't help you with your homework.

I tried looking for *bed sick* but hit a dead end.

Comment: I've heard *bedsick* before, as well as *bed ridden* (which only explicitly states one is *confined to bed*, and implies *because I'm sick or injured*).

Comment: @DanBron: Don't those imply more or less permanent conditions?

Comment: No, those are generally temporary, esp *bedsick*. *Bedridden* is also generally temporary, except when it's applied to a geriatric who is now too weak to stand (but is more typically applies to someone who has a serious illness or physical injury which prevents his arising). The words *invalid* and *incapacitated* connote a more permanent condition. See also *laid up*, which I'll post as an answer

Comment: The most natural phrasing for the "fill in the blank" problem is "I am currently sick in bed and can't help you with your homework."

Comment: I've never come across ***bedsick*** before, and it's [too rare to chart in NGrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=bedsick%2C+bedbound%2Cbedridden&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cbedbound%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cbedridden%3B%2Cc0). But although as that chart shows, ***bedridden*** is overwhelmingly the more common term, ***bedbound*** (which I would also use) does occur reasonably often.

Comment: I agree with @FumbleFingers, growing up in Australia, bedridden appears to be the more common term. I've also hear bedbound a lot but not as much as bedridden.

Comment: Generally sick and lying in bed (or "I'm sick in bed"), though "bedridden" is the normal US term for someone who is chronically confined to bed.

Comment: Though, come to think of it, what difference does it make whether they're in bed or not -- they're still being untruthful.  Is there some medical condition that requires that they tell untruths while reclining?

Answer (score 86, accepted):

> bedridden (ˈbɛdˌrɪd n) TFD
>
> adj.
>   confined to bed from illness.

Try this one on for size.

> I am currently **bedridden** and can't help you with your homework.

Comment: 'Bedridden' is possible. My own view, conformed by the Collins online dictionary, is that 'bedridden suggests a long term of confinement to bed.

Comment: True that. Thankfully, "Some conditions require that a person lie in bed all the time until recovered." does not imply a strict timespan for the patient's recovery, therefore giving us the freedom to leverage words, depending on the context's formality, style and a touch of personal preference.

Comment: I agree with @tunny: "bedridden" describes a chronic state, not a temporary one (which is presumably the condition described in the question).

Comment: We can go both ways here: 
"TEMPORARILY BEDRIDDEN RESIDENTS (Less than 14 days)
Persons who are bedridden because of a temporary illness or for recovery from surgery 
are allowed to be admitted to and retained in RCFEs. " 

Source: [This document](http://www.ccld.ca.gov/res/pdf/Bedridden.pdf)

Comment: _Bedridden_ can be used for someone confined to bed because of old age also.

Comment: Bedridden is perfectly applicable. While more commonly used for conditions lasting more than a few days, there's no hard rule about that. If I'm near paralysed with back pain, that will last only a few days but I'm not getting out of bed except to crawl to the medicine cabinet for more painkillers (literally).

Answer (score 17):

['Laid up'](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/laid-up) is possible. "I can't come in to work this morning. I am laid up with a bout of malaria".

Comment: +1 This seems to be what I'm looking for, although it sounds informal. Is it? If so, what would be a more formal equivalent?

Comment: or alternatively 'laid low'. See http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/lay+low

Comment: @paul: The definition your link provides doesn't imply lying in bed at all.

Comment: @ArmenԾիրունյան - true. Could be *laying low* on the floor ;-)

Comment: @paul: This idiom is new for me, but the definition implies that even if I am just a bit tired, but not lying in bed or on the floor, because of my illness, I'm still laid low. I am not arguing; I'm just trying to get the definition straight.

Comment: @ArmenԾիրունյան - :-) I have always understood it to mean that some illness has hit me hard and knocked me over. A picturesque way of saying no longer upright but horizontal.

Comment: In AmE "lying low" typically connotes hiding from somebody (often the police).

Comment: However, if I told my boss I was laid up with a bout of malaria he'd know I was lying.

Comment: "Laid low" and "laying low" are two entirely different terms.

Comment: Isn't this phrase too general? I thought you focus on sickness rather than other reasons.

Comment: I've never heard "laid up" in AmE before.

Comment: And I've never heard it in BrE (aka "English"), despite the dictionary entry and its citations. Just saying.

Comment: @Lightness Races in Orbit - Your comment *BrE (aka "English")* suggests to me that you think British English is *the"* true English. I hope I have misunderstood your words.

Comment: @tunny: Lighten up.

Comment: @tunny: But, since you asked... yes, I consider English to be _the language spoken in England_, as its name in fact suggests. Find other names for variants. And, yes, I know I'll get no traction on that here.

Comment: @Charles In British English too.

Comment: @Lightness Races in orbit - The various dialects of modern *English* English and other forms of *British* English, like all other varieties of the language, evolved from that spoken in most (not all) of England and some (not all) other parts of the British Isles in the early 16th century.  At no time has any form of English been the sole language of England, and at no time has the area in which the language is spoken been exclusively and entirely England. It's not even as though the language originated in England - its early forms arrived with people from Northern Germany and Scandinavia.

Answer (score 13):

[convalescing](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/convalescing):  *to recover health and strength after illness; make progress toward recovery of health.*
e.g., He was due to spend the next eight weeks convalescing

> I am currently convalescing and can't help you with your homework.

Source: Dictionary.com

---

Subjective interpretation

If I were to hear that someone was *bedridden*; yes I would understand that person to be sick and to be in bed, but I would also presume it was a serious illness, more so if the person is not elderly and frail. I would naturally assume that the person is unable to work for some time, perhaps weeks or even months. To be confined to one's bed 24 hours a day suggests something is seriously the matter. If this reflects the OP's case, than that suggestion is the most fitting and appropriate.

To be *laid up* describes someone who is *physically* (not *mentally*) unable to do any work. It suggests an injury, and therefore a  temporary state, and implies the person will return to work shortly. It's a phrasal verb; it's colloquial and very well-known (at least in BrEng). If an employer were to hear this over the phone, they may show concern, but not be unduly worried.

To be *convalescing* suggests that the person is no longer ill, but that the illness was a serious one. It suggests that the person is too weak to return to work, and needs absolute rest. This rest does not necessarily mean the person is confined to their bed 24 hours but neither does it exclude it. It depends on the illness or the injury subjected. A person who is convalescing is physically (and sometimes mentally) too weak to perform any strenuous task.

Comment: I know this word from personal experience.

Comment: You are not necessarily in bed if you are convalescing.

Comment: @tunny yeah, you're right. I'll leave it up anyway. It's a good word to know.

Comment: It's a useful word in the context of the original question.

Comment: No. The question asks for a word to use for somebody who is both ill and in bed. Convalescence refers to the period after illness, and is not necessarily done in bed so it fails on both points.

Comment: @Mari-LouA "Somebody who is both ill and in bed is probably better off being in hospital." Absolutely not. Most people have no need whatsoever to go to hospital because of the 'flu or a bad cold or any number of other diseases that are kind of unpleasant but not dangerous. Many people who have such a disease choose to spend a lot of time in bed (or possibly don't have the energy to feel they have much of a choice in the matter).

Comment: @DavidRicherby A bout of flu, bad cold, sore throat etc. doesn't mean you *have to* stay in bed all day though, does it? Unless, you're a man... If a person suffers from crippling backache, then, probably the bed is the only place that person can stay. Convalescence is a period of rest, which can follow a very bad bout of flu.

Comment: One advantage of *convalescing* is that you don't need to explain why, but with "bed ridden" or "laid up" you do. It would sound a bit odd to hear from an employee "I'm unable to come to work because I'm bedridden/laid up". It's only natural that you add the illness, see the above examples given. EDIT: *"Thanks for the highly constructive sexism"*  Oh, take a joke!

Comment: Keep in mind that someone who is convalescing is said to be *convalescent*. You might want to use that one instead.

Comment: @DavidRicherby I have to thank you for your constructive criticism (whose tone initially irked me) because it prompted me to defend my answer. My reference to men lying in bed all day with the flu or a simple cold, is a well-known cliché (at least in Italy it is) and I hoped it would have raised a chuckle or at worse a groan. I apologize if I offended your sensibility.

Comment: @Mari-LouA OK, thanks. Yes, that's a cliché in the UK, too but, until you know somebody well, you don't know if they're joking or if they actually believe it. So, yeah, I was offended at the time but I'm not any more.

Answer (score 13):

As a native speaker, I might use bedridden for a period longer than several days, but the term is not often used in casual conversation.  I would use "sick in bed" if it's just a few days, e.g:

> I am currently sick in bed and can't help you with your homework.

"Laid up" isn't used very much where I live (New England).  It's probably more common in other regions.

Comment: I've not heard "laid up", either, in (old) England, except to refer to disused ships

Comment: indeed, "laid up" is used for describing ships awaiting scrapping, not people who're stuck in bed.

Answer (score 8):

A sick person who is lying in bed is a bedridden fibber.

Comment: For our friends who are unfamiliar with *fibber* and the pun; a fibber is a *liar*, i.e. someone who tells *lies*. Someone who lies down (NOT *lays down*) is a person resting in a horizontal position.

Comment: Lay and lie always gets me mixed up!

Comment: Even with the explanation that took me a few seconds to figure out but it still made me chuckle. +1

Comment: Clearer explanation: Lying= a person who is telling lies / a person who is resting in a horizontal position. :)

Answer (score 6):

Sycamore Rockwell's suggestion of **bedridden** is one option, but in my experience, it carries a negative connotation and is rarely used to describe oneself.

A more neutral term, without these negative overtones, is **on bed rest.** This is most often used in connection with pregnancy, but in any context it carries the clear meaning that you've been instructed by a doctor not to get out of bed. To make it even clearer, you could be more explicit: **The doctor put me on bed rest.**

Comment: I don't agree with the bad connotations. It only means one thing: sick enough to be stuck in bed. I feel "bedridden" is definitely the most appropriate answer.

Comment: To me, "bedridden" carries connotations of permanence or, at least, a long-term condition. I'm not sure I'd describe somebody who's in bed for a couple of days because of the 'flu as "bedridden".

Answer (score 5):

The closest match for "confined to bed due to illness" is ***laid up***, as in

> *Tom won't be in the office this week, he's **laid up** with the flu.*

Also possible are literal ***bedsick*** (like you, I didn't find this word properly in a dictionary on a quick Google), and ***bedridden*** (which, as I note in the comments, strictly only denotes *confined to bed*, but typically connotes *due to illness or injury).

Comment: Why don't you provide a link to a dictionary for "laid up"?

Comment: @PierreArlaud http://www.thefreedictionary.com/laid+up

Answer (score 4):

If you want to stick to the sickness only, you can consider this self-explanatory word: ***sick-abed***.

> sick-abed - confined to bed (by illness)
>
> http://www.thefreedictionary.com/sick-abed

Note: It is used as *sick abed* also (unhyphenated).

Answer (score 3):

Bear in mind that (at least in America) phrases such as *I am currently bedridden* or *I am on bed rest* might be perceived as inappropriately antiquated and/or inappropriately dramatic. The most normal way of announcing that you're sick would be something like

> I am *currently recovering from a flu** and won't be able to help you today.

(* – or whatever the illness seems to be. Other common options include "food poisoning" or "a bad cold".)

Or, especially in an office setting,

> I'm *out sick* today and won't be able to help until tomorrow at the earliest.

Incidentally, some other too-dramatic terms for "a person who is confined to bed due to illness" include *convalescent*; *invalid* (which, as a noun, is pronounced "IN-vah-lid", as opposed to the usual adjective pronunciation of "in-VAA-lid"); and the more general *incapacitated* (as in "I am currently *incapacitated* by the flu and can't...")

Comment: +1 it's worth also mentioning the specific reasons why those terms are too dramatic: **convalescent** implies someone is slowly recovering from a very serious condition (e.g. after major surgery or cancer treatment), an **invalid** is someone with a long-term or permanent condition (but which is not necessarily terminal), and **incapacitated** implies someone has become *physically unable* to do things, temporarily or permanently - being *incapacitated* by flu implies it's so bad you actually can't get out of bed and need a carer to help you eat etc.

Answer (score 3):

Another option: invalid

"Invalid" does not carry the same inference that one is combined to bed, however, it does, in my experience seem to connote permanence of the state.

> Invalid
>
> noun: invalid; plural noun: invalids
>
> 1. A person make weak or disabled by illness or injury

Answer (score 1):

For someone who isn't bedridden, but is confined to bed due to illness, complicated pregnancy, etc., the term "on bed rest" is useful, particularly when it is prescribed by a physician.

Answer (score -1):

"Recumbent" is an appropriate term, like the type of bicycle.

Answer (score -4):

Another option is **infirm**.

> infirm: adj. Weak in body, especially from old age or disease; feeble.
>
> The American Heritage Dictionary of the English Language, 4th Edition

While it doesn't specifically refer to being stuck in bed, infirmed does connotate a level of weakness that often greatly limits one's activity.

> I am currently **infirm** and can't help you with your homework.

Comment: "Infirm" as an adjective can be used in this sense: "I am infirm." "Infirmed" as a verb is not idiomatic in any US or UK dialect I've ever heard.

Comment: Huh. It seems you are correct but I though I had seen that usage.

Comment: "Infirm" suggests a permanent or at least very long-term condition. If somebody can't help you with your homework because of infirmity, they'll probably never be able to help you again and I don't think that connotation is present in the question.