# What is 'man flu'?

Tags: meaning

I had been under the apparent misapprehension that the term ***man flu*** was used to distinguish it from ***bird flu*** or ***swine flu*** etc.

But according to Wikipedia this is how it is described.

> Man flu is a pejoratively used phrase that refers to the idea that
>   men, when they have a cold, exaggerate and claim they have the flu.
>   Whilst a commonly used phrase in the UK and Ireland, it is referred to
>   in other cultures[1] and there is a continuing discussion over the
>   scientific basis for the phrase.

A couple of people have recently told me they had *man flu*. Any ideas as to what they might have meant?

Comment: @Josh61 Well yes, I suppose that is what I need to know.  I think there may be people using the term without knowing what it means. Indeed what does it mean?

Comment: The Wikipedia quote tells you what it means. This is the only way that I have ever heard *man flu* used, though I can understand that some people may misuse the words.

Comment: Ha! I knew it, there had to be a word or expression. The last time I suggested something similar about men who catch the flu my head got bit off :)  :) [A bout of flu, bad cold, sore throat etc. doesn't mean you have to stay in bed all day though, does it? Unless, you're a man...](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/206235/what-do-you-call-a-sick-person-who-is-lying-in-bed/206238#comment437075_206236)

Comment: Were the people who told you they had "man flu" male or female? If male, all I can think of is that they shared your (mistaken, albeit understandable) impression that the term is used to distinguish avian flu or swine flu from the human variety. If female, they might have been referring to actual definition: i.e. they weren't technically so sick that they couldn't have gotten up to, say, fix dinner, but they chose to pretend they were men and exaggerated their symptoms.

Comment: You already gave the answer. As for what a couple of people said, it might have been said humorously or it might have been confused with [*human flu*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Human_flu). We don't know the context and the tone of their voice etc.

Comment: @Marthaª I would _almost_ be likely to think it the other way around. I have only ever heard man flu referred to in the first person (as it were) by men who are fully aware that their slight cough prevents them from nothing more than going to the library or the cinema, but still want to add a bit of, “I’M SICK, DAMMIT! PITY ME!!!” to the tone of what they’re saying. I’ve never heard a woman use it of herself at all. If the ‘man-as-opposed-to-other-animals’ definition had ever occurred to me (it hadn’t until I read this), it would definitely have been for women, not men.

Comment: Ask about when it was first coined, to reopen the question!

Comment: I agree with Mari-Lou A. The origin of the phrase would be a great question. You could also ask the term for the flu that is endemic to humans to distinguish from swine flu, bird flue etc. which I gave: *human flu*. [well, it is not hard to find but one might easily mix up the terms].

Comment: But the main question is...why man flu and not  woman flu? Is there an equivalent  expression referring to a female?

Comment: @Mari-LouA Both persons who told me they had had it were male, and both stressed how ill they had felt. My suspicion is that it is being used in two different ways.

Comment: Wasn't it clear if they using the term ironically, tongue-in-cheek so to speak? How can I possibly know for sure what they meant, if (1) you don't report their words exactly *in the question* (2) you don't explain what relationship you have with them. Personally, I think you should aim at etymology, far more interesting.

Comment: @Mari-LouA They did not appear to be using the term tongue-in-cheek. One of them was the coach of my grandson's football team and he was explaining why he couldn't be as active as normal as he was just recovering 'from this terrible man-flu'.

Comment: Why isn't this included in the question?

Comment: @Mari-LouA I could have given you the guy's height, approximate age, weight, marital status, and who he had once played football for. But were any of these things relevant?

Comment: *A couple of people have recently told me they had man flu.* and that's all you wrote. I'm not a mind reader, I strongly doubt anybody on EL&U is.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because there is nothing in the question to indicate why the Wikipedia definition is not sufficient. They meant it as an exaggeration men make in calling a bad cold "flu". If they meant something else, then any answer must be primarily opinion-based.

Comment: @AndrewLeach Are you suggesting that one should rely on Wikipedia explanations as 'sufficient'?